# How to filter custom property on api-platform entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, openapi, api-platform.com

I have an entity in Api Platform such as a team:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Basketball\TeamRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *   routePrefix="/v2",
 *   normalizationContext={"groups"={"public:read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 *   iri="http://schema.org/Team",
 *   collectionOperations={
 *     "get",
 *   },
 *   itemOperations={
 *     "get",
 *   },
 * )
 */
class Team implements ObjectManagerAware
{
  use \App\Entity\Traits\UUIDTrait;


  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Basketball\Event", mappedBy="teams")
   */
  private $events;


  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
  }


  /**
   * @return Collection|Event[]
   */
  public function getEvents(): Collection
  {
    return $this->events;
  }

  public function addEvent(Event $event): self
  {
    if (!$this->events->contains($event)) {
      $this->events[] = $event;
      $event->addTeam($this);
    }

    return $this;
  }

  public function removeEvent(Event $event): self
  {
    if ($this->events->contains($event)) {
      $this->events->removeElement($event);
      $event->removeTeam($this);
    }

    return $this;
  }

}
```

This all works and I can load teams and events. What I'd like to do is have a property on the API result that returns only upcoming events (not past events). What is the "proper" way to do that? I've tried adding a custom method such as

```
  /**
   * @return Collection|Event
   * @Groups({"public:read"})
   */
  public function getRemainingEvents(): ?Collection
  {
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('e')->from(Event::class, 'e');
    $qb->where(
      $qb->expr()->orX($qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(e.home)', $this->getId()), $qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(e.away)', $this->getId()))
    );
    $qb->andWhere('e.startDate >= :d');
    $qb->andWhere('e.startDate >= :d');
    $qb->setParameter('d', (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'));
    $qb->orderBy('e.startDate', 'ASC');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return new ArrayCollection($query->getResult());
  }
```

which does do sort of what I want but the api result using `application/vnd.api+json` doesn't list the events in the "relationships" the same way that the "events" property does. I've tried looking at the custom filters (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-filters) but don't understand how that would work for a custom method on the entity.

I'd like the `remainingEvents` to act the same as `events` and list the related items in the "relationships" of the response.

Is there some way to annotate it for the serializer or use the filter?

Answer (score 2):

I think you realize that using that approach (a method within an Entity retrieving data from Database) is wrong. Entities should be dummy.

About what are you trying to do, I think your best solution should be adding a DateFilter (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#date-filter) to the "Events" Resource, allowing you to do a `GET events?startDate[after]=2019-09-18`

And if you want to filter Events from a specific "Team" Resource, simply add another filter to the Event resource, a Search Filter (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#search-filter) to specify the Team, allowing you to do a:
`GET events?startDate[after]=2019-09-18&team=IRIofteam_OR_ID`